# How to run Interop.Excel.Application with command arguments?

Tags: c#, office-interop, office-addins, excel-interop, excel-addins

I need to pass arguments to new instance of excel and then read arguments from new instance via Addin.

I want to use this construction to open new excel application:

```
new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
```

Is there a way how to pass command line arguments for example as:

```
string argument = "TestArgument";
new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(argument);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to do this (I recommend running from Interop as fast as you can) you
can start the Excel application and then obtain a reference to it.

```
// start Excel with your command line arguments
var pathToExcel = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\excel.exe";
var commandLineArguments = "/whatever";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToExcel, commandLineArguments);

// get a reference to it
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

Interop is so evil that I feel almost unethical answering this. It opens the gates to endless suffering. If at all possible I recommend using something like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) to interact with Excel files.